# Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have react native project and tried to connect firebase. I did all steps according to documentation. I have jdk21 and react-native-firebase npm version is 19.1.1 . When i run my app console log is

Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-firebase_app:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\berke.gradle\caches\transforms-3\574f2ef9474ed1440ea9b3702093b1fd\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\berke.gradle\caches\transforms-3\574f2ef9474ed1440ea9b3702093b1fd\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

I tried add firebase to my project but i have so many errors with java :(

Comment: Try deleting and then reinstalling your Android SDK, this error is sometimes fixed this way

Comment: I fixed with delete jdk21 and downloaded jdk17